# IIS using the old SSL not the new SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

On May 30th, the Sectigo ROOT certificate has expired. We have changed the ROOT certificate with a valid one and generated new.pfx. We then updated it in the IIS (version 7.5, running under Windows Server 2008). While the certificate in the IIS server displays the chain correctly, the chain the browser is not correct. Also, when using online SSL Checkers for the url, it displays the old ROOT (expired ROOT) not the new ROOT updated. We did the following,

1. Generated the new.pfx with the updated valid CA ROOT certificate.
2. Removed the certificate from the "Server Certificates" in IIS.
3. Stopped the website, and the IIS server.
4. Removed the old certificate from the Windows using MMC.
5. Restarted the Windows Server.
6. Installed the new.pfx from the explorer.
7. Added the new.pfx to Windows using MMC.
8. Added the new certificate in "Server certificates" in IIS.
9. Used the new certificate in the website binding.
10. Restarted the Windows server.

However, even after doing all the above, when we load the website in the browser and check the certificate ROOT, it says old ROOT, not the new one. Also, used the SSL checker to verify the certificate, it says the ROOT certificate has expired (old one), not the new one.

I am not sure what is missing here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have to check if your changes in IIS Manager do write to HTTP API, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the certificate has been bound to the specific port, please type `Netsh HTTP` command at the command prompt on windows server2008.

```
Netsh http show sslcert |findstr 80
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/show-sslcert
Besides, you could configure a port with the specific SSL certificate with `Netsh Http add sslcert` command as well.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I have tried this and it displays correctly ie, ipport=0.0.0.0:443 with the correct certificate hash.

Comment: What about the result when accessing the website in Inprivate windows locally?
I am afraid I am lost. Check this guy's nice answer.
https://serverfault.com/questions/320495/iis-7-still-serving-old-ssl-certificate/768974

Comment: I added a new certificate in Personal store (*.domain.com) via MMC tool. After I restart, I see "Add Trust External CA Root" entry automatically added to the root cert store and that has the expired root certificate. If I disable that certificate my website is not loading. My suspicion is that the old certificate is still registered somewhere in the system but not sure where and not able to delete the old certificate entry. I used Digicert tool as well, but it is not showing the old certificate in the list.

Comment: When I try to use netsh, I now get this error "unable to load helper DLL: TMGNETSH.DLL" and there is no certificate list displayed.

Comment: @Abrahan Qian, I have resolved the DLL issue, however "netsh http show sslcert" command does not display anything, it returns with empty list, even though I have some certificates installed (via Windows install and in MMC). I am not sure why.

Comment: Anyway, cheers. I never experienced this scenario. I would like to see that you share the solution with us.

Comment: Our client found that there is a firewall which has the expired certificate installed. We have asked them to remove it from the firewall. However, they also have the new valid certificate in the firewall. However, somehow it is not picking up the valid certificate (from COMODO) but still fetches expired one (AddTrust from Sectigo). The problem continue to exist.

Comment: What about the result when accessing the website in private windows locally by using the localhost domainname? If SSL is configured on devices such as firewalls, web proxy. these certificates will take effect first.

Comment: Could it be because the OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, which might be old and not adapting to the new certificates? The FW is configured to exclude the expired certificates, but still I see old certificate when using SSL checker. The IIS or OS does not have any old certificate installed. Really stuck with this for weeks now :-(.